# How do I undo a checkin in ClearCase remote client

Tags: clearcase, checkin, clearcase-remote-client

I am using ClearCase remote client Version 7.1.1, and I am wondering if it's possible to delete a version that was checked in by mistake.
I know that in ClearCase, this is possible by choosing delete in the right click menu (Versions tree)
Anyone has the answer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Argh! [`rmver` (see man page)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmver.htm)?
I would strongly advice against such an operation which cannot be undone
(as I mention and detail in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295707/how-to-remove-a-version-in-clearcase/2295888#2295888), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446332/does-it-make-sense-to-permanently-delete-versions-from-a-vcs-as-part-of-a-normal/1446486#1446486) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147055/how-do-i-roll-back-a-file-checked-in-to-clearcase/2149141#2149141)).

And `rmver` is not possible in a CCRC client (even in the latest 7.1.2).

What I usually do is a graphical merge from the n-1 version to the n version in order to produce a n+1 version with the right content.