# Will there be any side effect if we delete a latest version from integration stream?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

we have delivered some set of packages to testing team and they completed testing.

In one of the package they report a defect and it was fixed and delivered to integration stream. But while deliver it asked for rebase and delivery contained reabase activity.

In rebase activity due to merging issues one of the file was modified in a package which had no defect.

As testing was already completed and the changes in the delivery is not required , our team wants to delete the latest version of a file [which is added as inadvertent] in integration stream.

If i delete the version of a file , will it have any ill-effect? ( For ex. while doing rebase again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a version is almost **never** a good idea.

- If that version has any hyperlink: **don't delete it**!
  (You can see it by looking at its version tree: look for any red arrow coming to or going from that version)
- If that version has any tag: **don't delete it**.
  That label is probably the result of a baseline, and that would break the integrity of said baseline.

I would recommend checkout that file, and replace its content with the right one, before check it in back in ClearCase.

See also:

- "[How do I undo a checkin in ClearCase remote client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257402/how-do-i-undo-a-checkin-in-clearcase-remote-client/4259212#4259212)": rmver is dangerous
- "[How do I roll back a file checked in to Clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147055/how-do-i-roll-back-a-file-checked-in-to-clearcase)": a subtractive merge is preferable to restore the right content in a new version