# ClearCase Find files pointing to version 0

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-automation

I'm trying to find a list of fiels pointing to Version 0 in a view. I have tried several options with the find command and could get the output that i wanted. Can someone help/direct me here? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that for a given branch, as I mention in "[Command to delete branches of Clearcase element with “0” versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183902/6309)":

```
cleartool find -avobs -branch'{
    brtype(mybranch)&&!
    (version(.../mybranch/1))}' 
     -print
```

You can replace `mybranch` by the name of a stream for which you want to clean any version /0.