# How to find newly created files in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearquest

When I check out files I have a new branch for those files. If I create a new file it is not added into the branch until I check the files back in. Before they are checked in the new file is under /Main/LATEST. Is there any way to find all files associated with a branch including newly created files?

So far I have only been able to find all files in the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I check out files I have a new branch for those files.

Only if your config spec is set to create a new branch, though. It has to [have a `-mkbranch` rule in it (as this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44414449/6309)

If you add to source control a file, without checking it in immediately, it creates a `/main/0` version (with an empty content file).
You can [search for those file having just a version 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22672143/6309):

```
cleartool find -avobs -branch'{
    brtype(mybranch)&&!
    (version(.../mybranch/1))}' 
     -print
```

But if the new file was not even added to source control, then it is a private file, and [you can list those as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7657120/6309) (`cleartool lsprivate` in a dynamic view, for instance).