# Is there a way to move a file from one branch to another in ClearCase?

Tags: branch, clearcase

A user checked new files on the wrong branch.  I would like to move them in the most efficient way there is a lot of them.  My first thought is to remove the element from the branch and have the user recheck in the files on the proper branch.  But I was hoping there was a way i could change the pointers?

```
/VOB/DIRECTORY/file@@/main/1.00/1 to /VOB/DIRECTORY/file@@/main/2.00/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there are a lot of files to checkout and move, **[`clearfsimport`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearfsimport.htm)** is a viable option.

Simply set a view to the destination branch, and import the files found in the source (and wrong) view.
See "[How can I use ClearCase to “add to source control …” recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309)"

That will checkout, add, modify or remove files in the destination view in order to mirror the ones from the source (here the source is a ClearCase view, but it could actually be any folder, ClearCase view or not, where the files are).

That will be enough to "recheck in the files on the proper branch", but that won't remove the versions from the wrong branch though, and I would advice *against* using `cleartool rmver` (even though [I used that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183902/6309)).
Perhaps a [subtractive merge is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2149141/6309).

Answer (score 0):

If you know where they are, and where you want them, you could:
1) Merge the directory and files over.
2) Use cleartool ln in a view in the destination branch to link in the files, and then merge the files individually.

If you use clearfsimport, and don't purge the added-in-the-wrong-place files, you can set yourself up for down-the-road "fun" caused by "evil twins."

Personally, since you know the files and directories that got added, where, when and by whom, you could do something like this (command lines are off-the-top-of-my-head:

1. Get the list of files to copy/merge

   `cleartool find -type d -element "created_by(baduser) && created_since(25-Jul-2016) && !created_since(26-Jul-2016)" -print > dirlist.txt
   cleartool find -type fl -element "created_by(baduser) && created_since(25-Jul-2016) && !created_since(26-Jul-2016)" -print > filelist.txt`
2. Pull the directories over by merging the parent directories while CD'd/set in a view using the destination path. Not knowing the OS involved I can't say which way you would need to parse this. If you use perl, you can grab the offset of the last instance of the directory separator and use that in substr to get the parent directory path. In the windows command prompt, you can do something like this:

   `SET SRCDRIVE=D:
   for /f "delims==" %x in (dirlist.txt) do cleartool co -nc %~px & cleartool merge -to %~px %SRCDRIVE%~px
   for /f "delims==" %x in (dirlist.txt) do cleartool co -nc %~px & cleartool merge -to %~px\%~nx %SRCDRIVE%~px\%~nx`

Yes, you can do all that in a single script, and do better error checking and not trying 40x to check out the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to merge them to the 2.0 branch (using a view selecting the 2.0 branch).  To identify the elements involved, you can run a 'cleartool find' command something like this:

`% cd /vobs/myvob`
`% cleartool find -all -version 'brtype(1.0) && created_by(user_x)' -print`

The 'created_since(date-time)' query might also be useful in the compound query.

Once you're convinced you have the right set of versions, you can use '-exec' in place of the '-print' to actually perform the merge.  It might look something like this:

`% cleartool find -all -version 'brtype(1.0) && created_by(user_x) && created_since(29-Jun)' -exec 'cleartool merge -to $CLEARCASE_PN -version $CLEARCASE_ID_STR'`

If you're happy with the results, check everything in.  Then you just have to decide if you need to remove the versions on the 1.0 branch (which you can do with another 'cleartool find ... -exec ...' command).