# Clear Case Error: File messed up after failed checkin

Tags: version-control, clearcase, checkin

We are using Jenkins for our continuous integration and in one job Jenkins checks in files into out Clear Case Integration Stream. Recently during one job the ClearCase checkin failed with the following message:

```
cleartool: Error: Operation "create_version" unavailable for manager "_xxx_file"    
(Operation pathname was:
"D:\Programs\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\lib\mgrs\_xxx_file\create_version")
cleartool: Error: Unable to store new version. cleartool: Error:
Unable to check in "Path/To/File/xxx
```

I was able to trace back the error, but the file in ClearCase is messed up since then. Every time someone tries to update his view connected to the integration stream he gets the following error message:

```
Unable to load "xxx": unknown error in VOB.
```

I can't see the file in the Rational Explorer or in Windows Explorer, but when I click "`Compare with Previous Versions`" on the containing folder I can see the file in both windows (belonging to current and previous version).
That behavior really confuses me.

I am pretty new to Clear Case and I would love to have a simple way to retrieve the previous version (something similar to `git revert`).

Answer (score 2):

> I would love to have a simple way to retrieve the previous version (something similar to git revert).

If you *really* think the new and problematic version was to be reverted, you could remove it completely with [`cleartool rmver`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmver.htm?pos=2) (as [I used it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183902/6309)). This is quite dangerous though.

But here, that version was likely never created, since the error message starts with "`Operation "create_version" unavailable`"

You can see this error message in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21328933) (about ClearCase MultiSite)

> This issue occurred after the following sequence of events:
>
> - VOBs were being moved from an old server to a new server along with upgrading ClearCase from an older version to 7.x.
> - A new type manager had been created on the old server along with an element type called `keyed_text_file_delta`.
>
> The error occurred because the new type manager and element type `keyed_text_file_delta` did not exist on the new server.

So double-check if the [type manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/type_manager.htm) "`_xxx_file`" still exists in your VOB, using [`cleartool lstype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm).

Comment: thx for your answer. I used the command "cleartool lstype -long eltype:_xxx_file", and according to the output the type manager exists. What I noticed is that the path "D:\Programs\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\lib\mgrs\_xxx_file" from the error message doesn't exist. Maybe that is a course for the error?

Comment: @airborne Strange: does `D:\Programs\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\lib\mgrs`exists (as a folder)? See for instance http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI06120

Comment: Yes, this folder exists.

Comment: @airborne So I ma not sure why it is looking for that (non-existent) path. Is there a type map defined which would reference said path?

Comment: I haven't found any.